# How do I properly join three MYSQL tables in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get information from multiple tables and the SUM of number of followers is not acting the way it should. I should be seeing 16 for follows and I'm seeing 256. Additionally there is only 40 "follows" logged in the database between all users.

$SQLTable_UserMeta is a key/pair table where a single user could have multiple rows which is why I have separate joins in the query.

```
SELECT $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`, $SQLTable_Users.`username`, $SQLTable_Users.`user_lastonline`, $SQLTable_Users.`user_registered`, $SQLTable_Users.`user_status`, SUM($SQLTable_Follows.`following`) AS follows, first_name.`value` AS FirstName, last_name.`value` AS LastName FROM $SQLTable_Users
LEFT JOIN $SQLTable_UserMeta first_name
    ON first_name.`user_id` = $SQLTable_Users.`user_id` AND first_name.`key` = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN $SQLTable_UserMeta last_name
    ON last_name.`user_id` = $SQLTable_Users.`user_id` AND last_name.`key` = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN $SQLTable_Follows
    ON $SQLTable_Follows.`follower_user_id` = $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`
GROUP BY $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`
ORDER BY `user_lastonline` DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: In general you are going to get dodgy results using GROUP BY this way. Turn on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: It would be nice to see some sample data and preferable a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @clinomaniac, you mean you actually want users to put effort into their questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the table $SQLTable_Follows just to get the count of followers, use a subquery

```
SELECT $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`, $SQLTable_Users.`username`, $SQLTable_Users.`user_lastonline`, 
$SQLTable_Users.`user_registered`, $SQLTable_Users.`user_status`, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM SQLTable_Follows WHERE SQLTable_Follows.`follower_user_id` =  $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`) AS follows, 
first_name.`value` AS FirstName, last_name.`value` AS LastName FROM $SQLTable_Users
LEFT JOIN $SQLTable_UserMeta first_name
    ON first_name.`user_id` = $SQLTable_Users.`user_id` AND first_name.`key` = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN $SQLTable_UserMeta last_name
    ON last_name.`user_id` = $SQLTable_Users.`user_id` AND last_name.`key` = 'last_name'
GROUP BY $SQLTable_Users.`user_id`
ORDER BY `user_lastonline` DESC LIMIT 100
```